# consistent barplot colors across graphs in Stata

Tags: graph, stata

I am outputting stacked bar plots in Stata, with each stacked bar ordered from bottom -> up : largest -> smallest Wins % per team.

```
clear
set obs 10
gen team = "yankees" if inlist(_n, 1, 6) 
replace team = "red sox" if inlist(_n, 2, 7) 
replace team = "mets" if inlist(_n, 3, 8) 
replace team = "nationals" if inlist(_n, 4, 9) 
replace team = "astros" if inlist(_n, 5, 10) 
gen wins = -10 + 20 * _n 
replace wins = wins[11 - _n] in 6/10 
gen year = cond(_n <= 5, 2013, 2014) 
gen season = "regular" in 1/10

set obs 16
replace team = "yankees" if inlist(_n, 11, 14)
replace team = "red sox" if inlist(_n, 12, 15)
replace team = "astros" if inlist(_n, 13) 
replace team = "mets" if inlist(_n, 16) 
replace wins = -10 + 30 * (_n-10) in 11/16
replace wins = wins[17 - _n] in 14/16 
replace year = 2013 in 11/13
replace year = 2014 in 14/16
replace season = "playoffs" in 11/16

foreach x in "regular" "playoffs"{
   preserve
   keep if season == "`x'"
   #delimit ;
   graph bar (mean) wins, over(team, sort(1) descending) over(year, label(ticks labs(small))) asyvars stack 
     ytitle("Wins (%)")
     title("Wins Percentages in `x'")
     blabel(bar, position(center) format(%9.0f) size(2.5) color(white))
     legend(size(2) rowgap(*.45) pos(6) rows (2) region(style(legend) fcolor(gs15) margin(medsmall)) colgap(*.75) symxsize(*.75) keygap(*.33));
    #delimit cr
   restore
```

[image]
[image]

The issue is that team colors vary across graphs, because not all regular season teams are present in the playoffs, and color is assigned alphabetically. For example, the red sox are yellow in graph 1, but green in graph 2.

From Stata's help menu, the only modification appears to be by bar #: 
`bar(#, barlook_options) look of #th yvar bar`

for example: 
`graph bar yvar1 yvar2, bar(1,color(green)) bar(2,color(red))`

I'm looking for

`graph bar yvar1 yvar2, bar(team=="Yankees",color(blue)) bar(team=="Red Sox",color(red))`

http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2011-03/msg00097.html offers guidance, but not the outcome described above.

Comment: Restructure so that each team is a separate variable and then you can associate bars with variables.

Comment: For a better answer, give an example of your problem that is reproducible. We can't use your data.

Comment: I've amended to include sample data. (Imagine this is part of a loop, as in there's another variable breaking down day vs night games, doubleheaders, etc. into separate categories, and each category has it's own graph, to see how, if the mets play no doubleheaders and are excluded from that separate graph, every team after them in the alphabet will have a different color,)

Comment: I've amended again to show the loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a partial answer only, to be supplemented if someone else or I can take it further.

Taking your sandbox example, and rewriting the code in ways not important for your question,

```
clear
set obs 10
gen team = "yankees" if inlist(_n, 1, 6) 
replace team = "red sox" if inlist(_n, 2, 7) 
replace team = "mets" if inlist(_n, 3, 8) 
replace team = "nationals" if inlist(_n, 4, 9) 
replace team = "astros" if inlist(_n, 5, 10) 
gen wins = -10 + 20 * _n 
replace wins = wins[11 - _n] in 6/10 
gen year = cond(_n <= 5, 2013, 2014) 

#delimit ;
graph bar (mean) wins, over(team, sort(1) descending) over(year, label(ticks labs(small))) asyvars stack 
  ytitle("Wins (%)")
  title("Wins")
  blabel(bar, position(center) format(%9.0f) size(2.5) color(white))
  legend(size(2) rowgap(*.45) pos(6) rows (2) region(style(legend) fcolor(gs15) margin(medsmall)) colgap(*.75) symxsize(*.75) keygap(*.33));
#delimit cr
```

my idea was to separate into a variable for each team:

```
separate wins, by(team) veryshortlabel
```

That then allows this kind of graph:

```
graph hbar (asis) wins? , over(team) over(year) nofill legend(off)
```

[image]

This might be a better foundation for your more complicated problems. (I am not sure whether we are expected to understand the baseball arcana. Indeed, is this baseball? These details are not universally understood.)

My own view is that stacking of bars would make the graph worse, but that is a different question.

Comment: Nick, I've amended again to include the loop in the data. In general, I concur that stacking bars isn't the best, though for the much more complex data I have (which I am trying to simplify with this contrived baseball data) I believe stacked bars is best. Thanks a ton for the help!