# Graph Bar Colors

Tags: graph, bar-chart, stata

I am having a similar problem as [Jonathan from his post in 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30653129/consistent-barplot-colors-across-graphs-in-stata).

Taking:

```
sysuse auto,clear
        # delimit ;
        graph bar price if make=="Ford Mustang" | make=="Ford Fiesta" | make=="Olds Omega",
            over (make, sort(hv_rank) reverse label(labsize(tiny)))
            ytitle("")
            horizontal title("test", size(medium))
            ;
        # delimit cr
```

Ideally I would like to color the bar red `if make=="Ford Mustang"`.

Comment: Indeed, this is basically the same question. To get a different colour, you need to put values in a different variable. See also http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=gr0049 for detailed discussion.

Comment: Adding:
  `separate price, by(make == "Ford Mustang")` and then
  `graph hbar (asis) price0 price1 if make=="Ford Mustang" | make=="Ford Fiesta" | make=="Olds Omega", nofill over(make, sort(price) descending) legend(off) ytitle("test")` won´t allow direct control over the actual bar graph colors though or am I missing something? 
I have no color scheme running so primary color is blue. Ford Mustang color is red.

Comment: You won't be guaranteed to get specific colours unless you ask for them: e.g. `bar(2, bcolor(red)) bar(1, bcolor(blue)) `.